# What is the cost of having multiple subscriptions in Pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

What is the cost of creating multiple subscriptions on a topic? Does creating more subscriptions affect the broker, Bookkeeper or both?

I'm assuming it only adds work load to the broker but the work increased by adding another subscription is minimal since it would only have to duplicate the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pulsar, a topic (or a partition) is owned by a single Broker meaning that all reads and writes go through that broker. Brokers cache bookies entries in memory so that it can dispatch messages directly to all consumers. This will avoid a network round-trip and a possible disk read on bookies.

In addition, you should note that a broker must send data over the network for each subscription. This can lead to network saturation if you have a very high throughput.

Moreover Bookies also have a write/reach cache to reduce disk access.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Could you elaborate a bit more about "a broker must send data over the network for each subscription"? My understanding is that subscription is only a configuration rule dictating how a set of consumers bound by the same rule reads from the topic. So does a broker actually send messages in topic to subscriptions? or does it send data directly to consumers?

Comment: Basically, if you have 10 MB/s of inbound data on a topic and you only have one consumer subscription (i.e. one application), then you will also have 10 MB/s of outbound data. But, if you have two applications with two distinct subscriptions, then data must be sent twice, i.e 20 MB/s of  outbound data.